# MongoDB Aggregation Query Leap Year

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a problem with queries.

Consider these documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d2b"),
    "title" : "Destroyer",
    "year" : 2018
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d2a"),
    "title" : "Aquaman",
    "year" : 2014
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d29"),
    "title" : "On the Basis of Sex",
    "year" : 1996   
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d28"),
    "title" : "Holmes and Watson",
    "year" : 1940
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d27"),
    "title" : "Conundrum: Secrets Among Friends",
    "year" : 1957
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d26"),
    "title" : "Welcome to Marwen",
    "year" : 2004
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d25"),
    "title" : "Mary Poppins Returns",
    "year" : 1997
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d24"),
    "title" : "Bumblebee",
    "year" : 2004
}
```

I am trying to group all leap years in these documents. I tried this code:

```
var query0 = {$group: {"_id": {"year": "$year"}}}

var query1 = {$addFields: {
      leap: {
        "$and": [
          {"$eq": [{"$mod": ["$year",4]}, 0]},
          {"$or": [
              {"$ne": [{"$mod": ["$year", 100]}, 0]},
              {"$eq": [{"$mod": ["$year", 400]}, 0] }
          ]}
        ]
      }
}}

var query2 = {$project: {leap: true}}

var query3 = {$group: {
      "_id": "$leap",
      "count": {$sum: 1}
  }}

var etapas =  [query0, query1, query2, query3]

db.genres.aggregate(etapas)
```

But I get this output:

```
{
    "_id": false,
    "count": 8 
}
```

It is wrong because the expect output is this:

```
{
    "_id": Leap,
    "count": 3
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.. but I cannot get the right output.

How can I fix this?

Thanks so much for your attention on me.

Comment: The first stage changes the documents so they look like `{_id:{year: ... }}`, just need to fix the field name in the next stage

Comment: @Joe I type it in every stage the field name: Leap; and I keep getting the same wrong output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

- First use a `$match` to get only Leap years. The condition is the same as you have.
- So with only leap years you can `group` them.
- Now the result is `4` because there are two `2004` so if you only want individual years you can use `addToSet` to avoid duplicates.
- And `$project` to get your desired output. Also you can use `"_id": 0` if you don't want to output the `_id`.

With this query you only need one `$group` stage and it is after the `$match` so there will be less data.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {"$eq": [{"$mod": ["$year",4]}, 0]},
          {"$or": [
              {"$ne": [{"$mod": ["$year", 100]}, 0]},
              {"$eq": [{"$mod": ["$year", 400]}, 0] }
          ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "year": {
        "$addToSet": "$year"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "Leap",
      "count": {
        "$size": "$year"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fM7d8ZkHaQu)

Comment: Thanks so much! @J.F. it works as I want to... thanks thanks, appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome and feliz navidad.

Comment: I had to try it (it's a bit of a hack) -  this `"$match"` also works: `{'$match': {'$expr': {'$eq': [{'$getField': {'field': 'day', 'input': {'$dateToParts': {'date': {'$dateFromParts': {'year': '$year', 'month': 2, 'day': 29}}}}}}, 29]}}}`.